# I need a way to copy images from one excel file to a new one in python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I tried using openpyxl and SheetImageLoader

Here's the best I could do, the script copies the images but works only if there's one sheet in the file and doesn't retain image size

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl_image_loader import SheetImageLoader
from io import BytesIO

# Load source workbook
src_wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:\\miso\\testy\\new_excel_file3.xlsx')
src_sheet = src_wb.active

# Create destination workbook
dest_wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
dest_sheet = dest_wb.active

# Load images from source sheet
image_loader = SheetImageLoader(src_sheet)

# Insert images into destination sheet
for row in src_sheet:
    for cell in row:
        if image_loader.image_in(cell.coordinate):
            img = image_loader.get(cell.coordinate)
            img_stream = BytesIO()
            img.save(img_stream, format='PNG')
            img_openpyxl = openpyxl.drawing.image.Image(img_stream)
            dest_sheet.add_image(img_openpyxl, cell.coordinate)

# Save destination workbook
dest_wb.save('C:\\miso\\testy\\new_excel_file.xlsx')
```

Comment: This also wouldn't work if there are no values in the columns to the right of the image or the column the image itself is in.

Answer (score 1):

Per my earlier comment; there is a fundamental issue with your code in the way you search for the image which you may not have noticed.
That is you are relying on searching a range of used cells for the image;

```
for row in src_sheet:
    for cell in row:
```

However if the image does not fall in this range it will not be found.
For example;
If I have an image in cell 'B2' on the sheet and values only in cell 'A1' and 'A2'.
When I run your code the image will not be found because only cells 'A1' and 'A2' will be checked for an image. 'B2' is not in the range and is not checked.
If I entered a value in cell 'B1' then cell 'B2' would be checked as the used cells range would now encompass 'B2', the same if there was a value in cell 'C1', 'D1' etc (regardless of whether column B remained empty other than the image or not). If the image was in cell 'B3' rather than 'B2' it would again be missed since the iteration range will only reach row 2 until one of the columns extended to, or beyond, row 3.

Like I said this may not be an issue for you if the image has always fallen within the iteration range but I wonder if its related to your statement ***but works only if there's one sheet in the file***. 
I don't see why that would occur and using your code sample, so long as the image *is* found, it doesn't matter how many sheets are in the source workbook and which sheet, the image will still be copied.

Anyway you may be better off to use code like below to find the image(s). This should return the location regards of their being any values in the sheet.

```
for image_loc in image_loader._images:
    image_list_loc = image_loc
```

The below is a modification of you code using the above search code;

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl_image_loader import SheetImageLoader
from io import BytesIO

# Load source workbook
src_wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('excel_file.xlsx')
src_sheet = src_wb['Sheet1']

# Create destination workbook
dest_wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
dest_sheet = dest_wb.active

# Load images from source sheet
image_loader = SheetImageLoader(src_sheet)

### Loop to find the images location and copy to the new work book/sheet
for image_loc in image_loader._images:
    print(f"Image located at: {image_loc}")
    img = image_loader.get(image_loc)
    print(f"Default Image Size: height: {img.height}, width: {img.width}")
    img_stream = BytesIO()
    img.save(img_stream, format='PNG')
    img_openpyxl = openpyxl.drawing.image.Image(img_stream)
    # img_openpyxl.width = 48
    # img_openpyxl.height = 48
    dest_sheet.add_image(img_openpyxl, image_loc)


# Save destination workbook
dest_wb.save('new_excel_file.xlsx')
```

The final issue ***doesn't retain image size***. By default Openpyxl will insert the image at its normal size. So if a 24 x 24 image is inserted in your source sheet and resized as 48 x 48, it will be copied into the new sheet as 24 x 24. However you can resize it back to the same 48 x 48 as the original using the `height` and `width` settings shown in the code.

```
img_openpyxl.width = 48
img_openpyxl.height = 48
```

The only problem is determining what the size of the image is on the originating sheet as I don't think that info is extracted by Openpyxl and the image object obviously contain the default image size i.e. 24 x 24. 
Off hand don't know if this can be extracted using Openpyxl, will need to look into further.